# Communication Device Class in Linux. Speed limit

Tags: ttyusb

Hi and happy new year.

I try to use Communication Device Class (virtual com) connection over the USB between stm32 board and laptop. On the laptop it is available as /dev/ttyACM0 device. I open it with settings

- 921600 bit rate
- 1 stop bit,
- no parity bit.

There is no physical serial interface. It is a direct USB connection.

For the test connection stm32 transmits predefined sequence. It is controlled by timer, 11uS for every transmit. On the laptop I use putty terminal for stream capturing and logging. In the log file I can see that some bytes were skipped. ...0x01 0x02 0x03 0x05 0x06 0x08 0x0B 0x0C 0x0E 0x16 0x17...

On the Windows machines gaps are even bigger then on Linux. What the really limit of bit rate? Where is a bottle neck? Is it possible to tune the driver for more bit rate? Any ideas what wrong?

Comment: Decrease bitrate. Usual serial bitrates are 1200,2400,9600,19200, 38400,  57600 and 115200 bps

Comment: 115200  - works, but actually it is to slow for me. I can get the same on a physical serial port. I thought that the USB would allow me to get more.

Comment: The `ttyACM0` device suggests that a USB-to-serial converter chip may be used internally by the board. What USB speeds is that converter capable of? If it's a USB 1.0 low-speed device, its *theoretical* raw USB maximum rate will be 1.5 Mbps, which will be further restricted by protocol overhead, so sustained 0.9216 Mbps USB-to-serial traffic might not be achievable in practice.

Comment: According to https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c8.pdf there is USB 2.0 full-speed interface. There is no any hardware converters, direct connection stm32 -> laptop USB